# Extended Hello World program

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm taking my first coding class and I'm trying to figure out how to make a Hello, World! program ask for my name and then reply with it. Our instructor gave us the lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int x;

    printf("hello, world!\n");
    printf("give me a number! ");
    scanf(" %d",&x);
    printf("%d is my favorite number!!\n",x + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

which is a working hello world program when compiled, but we have to make it ask for our name as well, which I cannot figure out.

This was his hint:

```
#include <string.h>

char s[512];                        //allocate an array to hold a string
printf("type in some stuff: ");
fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin);           //read in a string of characters
s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';            //remove the newline character
printf ("you typed %s!\n", s);
//NOTE: this code fails if string is larger than 511 characters
```

but seeing as I know literally nothing about coding it isn't very helpful to me.

The end result is supposed to look like this when prompted with "hello"

```
What is your name? Fred
hello Fred
give me a number! 10
100 is my favorite number!!
```

Edit: I tried modelling the "what is your name?" after the "give me a number" line but it didn't work.

Edit 2: This code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char s[512];

    printf("What is your name? ");
    fgets(s,sizeof(s), stdin);
    s[strlen(s) - 1] =  '\0];
    printf ("Hello %s!\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

returns an error which apparently doesn't fit in the post.

Comment: It looks like to me all you have to do is change the prompt.

Comment: I can't see the question\/

Comment: Sorry I messed up. I posted what the end result is supposed to look like. I can't just change the prompt because I don't know how to make it just ask for my name (am I supposed to define a variable at the end of the line, and if so, how?)

Comment: What I mean is it looks like your instructor only wants you to change a few things, not write the program yourself.

Comment: and Will be deleted after it was examined newline exists. also `x+1` -> `x * 10` or `x + 90`

Comment: At your new edit: you need to include `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just change the prompt?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// This is the main function. Anything inside the { } will be run by the computer
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char s[512]; // This will be the variable that holds the user's name (or whatever they type in)                     
    printf("What is your name? "); // Ask the user for their name
    fgets(s,sizeof(s), stdin); // Get whatever the user types in and put it in the variable s
    s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0'; // Remove the newline character from s (what the user typed in)
    printf ("Hello %s!\n", s); // Print out "Hello" followed by whatever the user typed in (their name, which is stored in the variable s)

    // End the main function
    return 0;
}
```

Output should be

```
What is your name? (User types in Fred)
Hello Fred!
```

Comment: Would I put this after the int x; line? I'm sorry I sound like such na idiot but I literally have had one CS class at this point and this was thrown at us on Monday, and the textbook hasn't really covered anything like this yet.

Comment: I have my code set up as 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
    char s[512];
    printf("What is your name? ");
    fgets(s,sizeof(s), stdin);
    s[strlen(s) - 1] =  '\0];
    printf ("Hello %s!\n", s);
    return 0;
    }

Which looks correct, but when compiled it returns...

Comment: @NewCsStudent432 Not to be rude, but what's wrong with asking your instructor or on-campus tutors?

Comment: I'm going to put what it returns in my main post for formatting

Comment: The quiz is tomorrow at 9am and I have emailed the instructor already.